# Spring rabbitmq send to exchange with dynamic binding

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I try to use TopicExchange for masking a messages.

Config:

```
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"  host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest"/>

<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<rabbit:queue name="sample.queue"/>

<rabbit:admin id="rabbitAdmin" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<rabbit:annotation-driven container-factory="rabbitListenerContainerFactory"/>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
```

Component:

```
@Component
public class JmsComponent {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsComponent.class);

    private final TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange("sample.exchange");

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Queue queue;

    private String received;

    public void send(String msg) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("sample.queue", new SimpleMessage(msg));
    }

    public void bindToKey(String keyMask) {
        BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(keyMask);
        rabbitTemplate.setExchange(exchange.getName());
    }


    public void sendByKey(String key, String msg) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(), key, new SimpleMessage(msg));
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "sample.queue")
    public void handle(SimpleMessage message) {
        log.info("================ Received  " + message.getMsg());
        received = message.getMsg();
    }

    public String getReceived() {
        return received;
    }
```

When I used send (before including TopicExchange) - all works fine. Messages was sent to queue directly and handle() has receive it.
But for TopicExchange.... I try to use it that:

```
@Test
public void bind() throws InterruptedException {
    jmsComponent.bindToKey("qq");
    jmsComponent.sendByKey("qq", "message");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Assert.isTrue("message".equals(jmsComponent.getReceived()));
}
```

Test is fail always but in log I see this - DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Publishing message on exchange [sample.exchange], routingKey = [qq]
What is wrong???
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This...

```
BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(keyMask);
```

...does nothing except create a `Binding` object and then throw it away. You need to take that `Binding` object and call `declareBinding` on the admin. You also need to declare the exchange.

Since you have an admin in your context; the easiest thing to do is add the `<rabbit:exchange/>` to the context (along with the binding). See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration).

```
<rabbit:queue id="myQueue" name="sample.queue"/>

<topic-exchange name="sample.exchange">
    <bindings>
        <binding queue="myQueue" pattern="bucket.#"/>
    </bindings>
</topic-exchange>
```

By the way, topic exchanges are intended for routing by key patterns; if you simply want to route/bind with a fixed key, like `qq` then use a direct exchange. See the [RabbitMQ Tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html).

Answer (score 4):

I change my component use answer of Gary Russell:

- I've add

  ```
  @Autowired
  private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
      rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
  }
  ```
- and modify the bind method:

  ```
  public void bindToKey(String keyMask) {
      Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(keyMask);
      rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding); // re-declare binding if mask changed
      rabbitTemplate.setExchange(exchange.getName());
  }
  ```
- and test became works after it!

More, I've add change binding mask at runtime:

```
@Test
public void bind() throws InterruptedException {
    jmsComponent.bindToKey("qq");
    jmsComponent.sendByKey("qq", "message");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Assert.isTrue("message".equals(jmsComponent.getReceived()));

    jmsComponent.bindToKey("eeeee");
    jmsComponent.sendByKey("eeeee", "message one");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Assert.isTrue("message one".equals(jmsComponent.getReceived()));
}
```

All works.